# Codeigniter custom email validation rules

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, email

Can someone please provide some advise on how to go about creating custom validation rules for Codeigniter.

The website I am working on is for university students and only allows users to register if they use their university email address.

Here is an example of the type of validation I am trying to achieve:

Only allow emails that end with:

```
array(
    '0' => '@uni-email-1.com',
    '1' => '@uni-email-2.com',
    '2' => '@uni-email-3.com',
    '3' => '@uni-email-4.com',
);
```

I am still quite new to codeigniter and I am not sure how to create this type of validation.

Any assistance is very much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sure, how's this?

```
function index()
{
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

    $this->load->library('form_validation');


    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'callback_email_check');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        //fail
    }
    else
    {
        //success
    }
}

function email_check($str)
{

    if (stristr($str,'@uni-email-1.com') !== false) return true;
    if (stristr($str,'@uni-email-2.com') !== false) return true;
    if (stristr($str,'@uni-email-3.com') !== false) return true;

        $this->form_validation->set_message('email', 'Please provide an acceptable email address.');
        return FALSE;

}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
public function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|callback_email_check');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('form');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('formsuccess');
        }
    }

    public function email_check($email)
    {
        if(stristr($str,'@uni-email-1.com') !== false) return true;
        if(stristr($str,'@uni-email-2.com') !== false) return true;
        if(stristr($str,'@uni-email-3.com') !== false) return true;

        $this->form_validation->set_message('email', 'Please provide an acceptable email   address.');
        return FALSE;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is actually more related to PHP than CI. Basically, you should string match inserted email address to each ending string you provided. If there is a match - allow registering, if not - output an alert or something and don't allow it.

Answer (score 1):

If your university has an LDAP directory, then you can do authentication over it, instead of having another base. Single Sign On is a very good system for use in institutions such as universities

Answer (score 1):

Try something like following,

```
$formatArr = array("@uni-email-1.com", "@uni-email-2.com" "@uni-email-3.com");

$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'callback__check_email');

//then the validation function
function _check_email() {
   $email = $this->input->post("email");
   $emailLastPart = array_pop(explode("@", $email));
   if(!in_array($emailLastPart, $formatArr)) {
      $this->form_validation->set_message('email', 'Please provide valid email address.');
      return FALSE;
   }
   return TRUE;
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for your time and input, however I was unable to get this code to work.

Answer (score -1):

You can validate email by html5 simple code

with pattern